# How to make network call from recycler-view adaptor with ToggleButton

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-thread

I have button in recycler view when I click it I want to change the text of button and make network call with volly.

I am getting this Exception

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

So, I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)
and created a class extending Thread class and made the network call in it, and called it from adapter

But it is still showing the same error.

I am not understanding what I need to execute on main thread and what on new thread.

This is the call from the recycler-view adapter

```
pdc_viewHolder.toggleButton_paymentStatus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean toggleOn) {
                if (toggleOn) {
                    // Toggle on = PAID
                    // Change the color of background

 pdc_viewHolder.activity_dashboard_recyclerView_row_toggleButton_paymentStatus.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_layout_toggle_button_dashboard_paid_state));

                   MyThread myThread = new MyThread(bankNameAdap, context);
                    myThread.start();

                } else if (!toggleOn) {
                    // Toggle off = PENDING
                     //Change the toggle button background 
 pdc_viewHolder.activity_dashboard_recyclerView_row_toggleButton_paymentStatus.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_layout_toggle_button_dashboard_pending_state));


                     MyThread myThread = new MyThread(bankNameAdap, context);
                    myThread.start();

                }
            }
        });
```

and I am calling Volley-POST method in MyThread class  in run() method.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes. You can do using interface. Check this link: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321005/how-to-access-component-from-another-view-in-android/54321445?noredirect=1#comment95462767_54321445)

Comment: Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: the error you are getting means that you have tried to do something on the wrong thread. But nobody knows what.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54415542/edit) the question with related code which is causing the error.

Comment: I have posted the code

Comment: I tried your answer but didn't work @PratikSatani

Comment: What is the issue you did face when trying my answer?

Comment: @PratikSatani  I got the same exception. bcz it is same as calling the method in Activity directly from adaptor. It doesn't deal with threads.

Comment: Do one thing use runOnUIThread to call it

activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   
  }
});

Comment: Is this work for you?

Comment: @PratikSatani no, it's giving the same error